# igualar dimensiones de np.arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Desde ayer estoy con un ejercicio donde tengo que añadir a un np.array vacío los elementos mayores en una primera columna y los menores en una segunda columna de un np.array anteriormente creado. He intentado de todo, incluso he barajado la opción de hacerlo con python, me saldría un código enorme para muy poco. Mi intención es sacar los elementos mayores y menores de cada fila del array y añadirlos a un np.empty que he igualado en dimensión al array original y sin embargo me dice que el array primero tiene dos dimensiones y el segundo 0 aunque si pregunto por separado a cada array me dice numpy que tienen dos dimensiones ambos. He hecho esto, primero el código del array original

```
b=np.random.rand(25)*50
b_round=[round(x,2) for x in b]
C=np.array(b_round)
C.shape=(5,5)
print(C)
type(C)
print(C.ndim)
```

Y su resultado

```
[[14.11  0.45 45.58  6.19 40.61]
 [20.07 11.98 24.97  5.33 43.61]
 [30.73 10.1  24.36 13.1  47.11]
 [42.75  2.43  6.29 16.42 31.48]
 [49.09 23.95 44.02 40.29  9.38]]
2
```

Siguiente, lo que estoy haciendo para sacar los valores máximo y mínimo de cada fila

```
array = np.empty((5,2))
print(array.ndim)
#array.shape=(5,2)
for x in C:
    array=np.append(array,x.max(),axis=1)
```

Y el mensaje de error

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 
has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradezco, es una situación un tanto desesperada ya que hay que presentar una serie de ejercicios hoy y éste es uno de ellos
Bueno he hecho un cambio de np.array a lista para trabajar así, en principio funcionaba pero cuando le he puesto un shape para darle forma (5,2), lo pide el ejercicio, me da otro mensaje de error. Nuevo código

```
lista2=[]
for i in lista1:
    lista2.append(max(i))
for j in lista1:
    lista2.append(min(j))
print(lista2)
c=np.array((lista2))
c.shape(5,2)
print(c)
```

Mensaje de error

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Una ayuda sería bienvenida

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de crear un array vacío para después ir agregando columnas puede ser más sencillo que directamente crees el array resultado usando `np.array()` y pasándole los valores que debe tener mediante una lista. Dentro de esa lista usarías `C.max()` y `C.min()` para obtener respectivamente los máximos y mínimos (no es necesario ningún bucle).

Es decir, propongo:

```
array = np.array([C.max(axis=1), C.min(axis=1)]).T
```

### Explicación

`C.max()` sin parámetros te da el mayor de todo el array `C`, pero al pasarle el parámetro `axis=1` estás pidiendo el máximo de cada fila (`axis=0` te daría en cambio el máximo de cada columna). El resultado es un array unidimensional.

Análogamente `C.min(axis=1)` te da el mínimo de cada fila. Al unir ambos en una lista `[ ... ]` y pasar esa lista a `np.array()` se creará un array bidimensional, en este caso de dos filas y 5 columnas. Ya que quieres lo contrario (5 filas y dos columnas) añado un `.T` para obtener la matriz transpuesta.

### Ejemplo

Siendo `C` la siguiente:

```
[[42.12  1.33 31.   47.07 32.  ]
 [ 5.28  9.85 22.73 44.3  38.32]
 [40.01 49.21  1.29 18.15 17.34]
 [30.05 16.13 10.75 46.72 12.28]
 [10.45 15.9  28.94 23.49 15.13]]
```

el resultado del código anterio sale:

```
[[47.07  1.33]
 [44.3   5.28]
 [49.21  1.29]
 [46.72 10.75]
 [28.94 10.45]]
```

## Aclaración adicional

Lo que intentabas hacer tú tenía dos errores. De un lado usabas `C.max()` sin parámetros, lo que causaba como resultado un solo número (el máximo de todo el array) en vez de una columna de números.

Pero más importante, `np.empty((5,2))` no genera un array "vacío" (esto es, sin columnas). Genera de hecho un array de 2 columnas y 5 filas y simplemente no inicializa sus valores con ningún número en particular, por lo que contienen "basura" (números al azar). Tratar de extender ese array para añadirle más columnas no causaría el resultado que buscas. Lo que quieres es reemplazar esos valores "basura" por los máximos y mínimos. Esto se haría así:

```
array = np.empty((5,2))
array[:,0] = C.max(axis=1)
array[:,1] = C.min(axis=1)
```

Fíjate cómo al asignar a `array[:,0]` se están sustituyendo todos los elementos (eso significa el `:`) de la columna `0` por lo que haya al otro lado de la asignación.

Yo prefiero usar `np.zeros()` en vez de `np.empty()`. Esta función crea también un array de las dimensiones que le pidas, pero inicializado con ceros. Es cierto que en este caso no tiene mucho sentido inicializar con ceros porque vas a sobreescribir esos valores seguidamente, y por tanto sería más eficiente usar `np.empty()`, pero creo que usar `np.zeros()` es menos confuso pues no puede llevarte a engaño y hacerte pensar que el array creado es "vacío" (sin datos).

Comment: Para el primer caso, comprendo que con esa sola línea, ya obtendría resultado. Y comprendo que para el siguiente caso sí hace falta bucle

Comment: No, el segundo caso tampoco requiere bucle porque tu bucle era para iterar por las filas de C y buscar el máximo de cada fila. No es necesario tal bucle porque `C.max(axis=1)` ya te devuelve en una sola operación un vector-columna que contiene los máximos de cada fila

Comment: Si quisieras hacerlo en forma de bucle entonces sería algo del estilo: `for i in range(len(C)): array[i,0] = C[i].max(); array[i,1] = C[i].min()` pero no tiene sentido hacer este bucle pues es más eficiente dejar que numpy lo haga por tí (además de ser más difícil de leer el código)

Comment: Pues no me da ningún resultado, he probado los dos tal como los has puesto y no lo imprime, algo debo estar haciendo mal

Comment: Bueno, no  lo imprime porque no le he pedido que lo haga :-) ¿Has puesto un `print(array)` al final?

Comment: Antes lo pondría mal, porque no salió, ahora sí con el primero, con el siguiente no sé el motivo pero no sale, seguro es un error mío. Muchísimas gracias, todavía me quedan unos cuantos más y no me sale ninguno.Saludos